# Exception in NSAppTransportSecurity found Insecure status In MobSF

Tags: ios, app-transport-security

App Transport Security (ATS) is disabled on the domain '{'NSAllowsArbitraryLoads': True}'. Disabling ATS can allow insecure communication with particular servers or allow insecure loads for web views or for media, while maintaining ATS protections elsewhere in your app.

Comment: please check this issue - https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF/issues/560#event-1617055208

Comment: Could you develop a bit your question? This seems to be just the exception copy-paste. What did you try to do to solve your problem?

Comment: @xavier I am getting App Transport Security (ATS) is a disabled issue where I already added  App Transport Security in the plist file